# How to control .htm file in python

Tags: python, html, subprocess, app-offline.htm

I am opening a .htm file through code in python. It is opening in chrome. After that I am removing the file as

```
ss=subprocess.Popen(FileName,shell=True)
ss.wait()
removeTempFile(FileName)
```

subprocess is not waiting and suddenly removeTempFile is executed. So, **This webpage is not found** error is occuring as file is removed. This code works fine with .odt, .txt file but causing trouble with .htm file only

Comment: Have you considered using `.communicate()`

Comment: this depends on what the external app does. if the call returns immediately python will remove the file right after that. this might be the case if chrome opens the file in an existing tab and does not keep the new process around, but chrome might behave the same even when doing a cold startup. maybe you could try to use a another browser, see if it behaves the same, and narrow down the problem.

Comment: @Jakob Bowye yes, i tried with that also. It didn't work

Comment: You could try using the [webbrowser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html#module-webbrowser) module instead. It might wait for the browser to finish depending on your OS.

Comment: I don't get how this is supposed to work. You should normally pass a binary to Popen to run it in a shell, and not an application file. Probably your OS detects the type of input and spawns an application that handles it, and in this case starts the browser in new thread and returns immediately. Shouldn't you use something like Popen('/path/to/browser', '--file', FileName) or similar?